# PI4IOE5V96248 communication with an Orange Pi zero 2 - Python

Tags: python-3.x, i2c, orange-pi, smbus

As you know there are almost none Raspberry Pi on the market (sold out, not available) where I got an Orange Pi zero 2 and for increasing the GPIOs I bought a PI4IOE5V96248 Expander. (48-bit I/O pins )

This communicates by I2C,

Was created the next python code:

```
import smbus
import time

bus = smbus.SMBus(3)
slave_address = 0x20

def set_led_state(states):
    try:
        bus.write_i2c_block_data(slave_address, 0x00, states)
        print("Address acknowledgment: Received")
        print("Data byte acknowledgment: Received")
        print(f"Address byte sent: 0x{slave_address:02X}")
        print(f"Data bytes sent: {[f'0x{s:02X}' for s in states]}")
    except IOError:
        print("Address acknowledgment: Not received")
        print("Data byte acknowledgment: Not received")

# Define LED states
LED_OFF = 0x00
LED_1 = 0x01
LED_2 = 0x02
LED_3 = 0x04
LED_4 = 0x08
LED_5 = 0x10
LED_6 = 0x20
LED_7 = 0x40
LED_8 = 0x80

# Prompt the user to select an LED
def prompt_led_selection():
    led = int(input("Enter the LED number (1-48) to switch on (0 to exit): "))
    if led == 0:
        return None
    elif led < 1 or led > 48:
        print("Invalid LED number. Please try again.")
        return prompt_led_selection()
    else:
        return led

# Repeat the LED selection until the user chooses to exit (0)
while True:
    selected_led = prompt_led_selection()
    if selected_led is None:
        break

    # Calculate the LED state based on the selected LED number
    state_index = (selected_led - 1) // 8
    bit_position = (selected_led - 1) % 8

    # Create an array of LED states
    states = [LED_OFF] * 6
    states[state_index] = 0x01 << bit_position

    set_led_state(states)

    # Print the selected LED number
    print(f"LED {selected_led} switched ON")
    time.sleep(0.1)  # Delay for 2 seconds

# Turn off all LEDs
set_led_state([LED_OFF] * 6)
print("All LEDs are OFF")
```

While the previous code can work more or less, the issue is that the pin 9 is recognized as 1. Then the Pin 40 is recognized as 48. Where from the 0-8 the pins are not working.

The datasheet for the PI4IOE5V96248 says:

> To write, the master (microcontroller) first addresses the slave device. By setting the last bit of the byte containing the slave address to logic 0 the Write mode is entered. The PI4IOE5V96248 acknowledges and the master sends the first data byte for IO0_7 to IO0_0. After the first data byte is acknowledged by the PI4IOE5V96248, the second data byte IO1_7 to IO1_0 is sent by the master.
> After the second data byte is acknowledged by the PI4IOE5V96248, the three data byte IO2_7 to IO2_0 is sent by the master and so on.

Any idea what could be the source of the problem?

I tried mapping LED by LED, and I tried modifying the section code of the # Create an array of LED states

I tried modifying also the section for # Calculate the LED state based on the selected LED number.

But even there was worst cases where there was not any led switching on, so I shared one that at least is working from 9-48 pins (gpio 8-47)

Comment: this question looks good to me, but to be clear... While there is a stack overflow team, they are not the ones answering your questions, that would be your fellow users, this site is for users, by users. I wish I could help, but I have no experience with this PI and expansion board specifically. I wish you the best of luck

Comment: @iggy12345, hello, thanks for answering, next time I will start with:  Dear Stack overflow fellow users.  ;)

Comment: No need to greet. What has to be done will be done ;-)